# Imagick Resize not working

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, image-resizing, imagick

I'm running an \Imagick::resizeImage() on a png file, and the result is TRUE, but nothing is happening to the image. No errors at all.

Here is my code:

```
$imagick = new \Imagick("/var/www/silex.dev/uploads/media/test.png");
$status = $imagick->resizeImage(200, 200, \Imagick::FILTER_CATROM, 1);

//$status = true
```

test.png exists. It has 0777, the media/ folder has 0777 and the uploads/ folder has 0777. It just simply isn't resizing.

I have also run:

```
if( class_exists('\Imagick') )
```

which resolves true also.

Here's a screenshot of the file properties, the test.png and its file path.

[image: test]

Does anyone know if I am missing something?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either save the file or send it to a browser to see the resized version. Imagick doesn't alter files in place.

So either `$imagick->writeImage("./output.png")` or `echo $imagick->getImageBlob();`.

Comment: AH so I'm resizing in memory. In which case: `bool Imagick::writeImage ([ string $filename = NULL ] )` Will do the trick?

Comment: ImageMagick has a `mogrify` command that manipulates images in place.